# Android Master/Detail Flow multiple adapter layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, tablet, master-detail

We have an app that supports different ListView Adapter layouts, if the screen is wide enough it shows more fields in the list.

We did that creating different `list_entry_item.xml` files for different layout qualifiers: `layout`, `layout-w600dp` etc.

```
res
\__ layout
    \_ list_entry_item.xml   (narrow layout)

 __ layout-w600dp
    \_ list_entry_item.xml   (wide layout)
```

Now we're creating a Tablet Master/Detail Flow for the screen, but have the problem that even though the Master-List is narrow, it still loads the wide `layout-w600dp/list_entry_item.xml`. I assume Android only looks at the whole screen to decide which layout file to load, and not the context in which it's loaded.

The current "solution" is to move the narrow `layout/list_entry_item.xml` to a new generic `layout/list_entry_item_narrow.xml` and have both the `layout/list_entry_item.xml` and the tablet `layout-w900dp/list_entry_item.xml` include the generic `list_entry_item_narrow.xlm` folder.

```
res
\__ layout
    \_ list_entry_item_narrow.xml (narrow layout)
     _ list_entry_item.xml        (includes narrow.xml)

 __ layout-w600dp
    \_ list_entry_item.xml        (wide layout)

 __ layout-w900dp
    \_ list_entry_item.xml        (includes narrow.xml)
```

Is this really the best way to handle it? It seems unnecessarily complitated.